# Python/Vercel getting 'FUNCTION_INVOCATION_TIMEOUT' if return stream as responde in serverless function in Python

Tags: python, node.js, vercel

I'm trying to use Python Fastapi StreamingResponse function to redirect stream from 3d party url, but i'm getting 'FUNCTION_INVOCATION_TIMEOUT' error because it runs more than 10 seconds.
Code example:

```
client = httpx.AsyncClient(http2=True)
response = await client.send(client.build_request('GET', f'https://{url}'), 
                                       follow_redirects=True,
                                       stream=True)
return StreamingResponse(response.aiter_raw())
```

But if i'm using nodejs app and trying to return stream via JS fetch function -  it working fine. I'm just using

```
return fetch(url)
```

where url - is url for stream. Without any timeout error.
Please help me to make similar Response for python.

Tried to use Fastapi, Flask as server framework and as http client - httpx, requests, urllib with same output. Vercel killing function by timeout.

As workaround I added endpoind for serverless nodejs function which respondes with stream.
My vercel.json config:

```
{
  "builds": [
    { "src": "main.py", "use": "@vercel/python" },
    { "src": "stream.js", "use": "@vercel/node"}
  ],
  "routes": [
    {"src": "/api/(.*)", "dest": "main.py"},
    {"src": "/stream/(.*)", "dest": "stream.js"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Try to put in setTimeout to 1000

Comment: I'm using free vercel account. Maximum timeout is 10 seconds. But my question is why for nodejs it seems no timeout for function which is returning fetch(url). Maybe it's just redirect readable to writable socket and not iterate it. I'm wondering if it possible make similar response in python.